# Is it possible to re-cipher with Paillier?

Tags: encryption, elgamal-encryption, paillier

I know that with ElGamal we can re-cipher and get a second ciphertext equal to the first.

Is it possible with [Paillier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) too?

---

When saying "re-cipher", I mean "A sends me a message, that is encrypted with my public key, I somehow modify the ciphertext, so that it is now encrypted for C without actually having simply decrypted and encrypted".

Comment: Don't you just choose a random $0 < r < n$ and compute $c \cdot r^n \mod n^2$?

Comment: Sorry, @ogogmad. Could you explain it better? I'm a newbie and I don't understand what you're saying...

Comment: The Paillier cipher has two important properties A) it is asymmetric, that is encryption of a known plaintext requires only public information (the public key). B) it is homomorphic, that is (within some conditions) a ciphertext for the sum of two unknown plaintexts can be deduced from the ciphertexts for the two plaintexts, using only public information. Is it acceptable that the re-encryption is symmetric (that is can only be performed with a secret key shared between the one doing and undoing the encryption)? And what (if any) must remain of the homomorphic property after re-encryption?

Comment: Are you looking for [proxy re-encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_re-encryption) or something else? You seem to be looking for something slightly different since it appears you want to still be able to decrypt the message. Please correct me if I am wrong.